# String initialisation containing zero --> compiler bug or intended behavior?

Tags: c++, string, utf

I try to define some hard coded utf sequences.

like

```
    static std::string const cUTF_16_BE_BOM = "\xFE\xFFTest";
    static std::string const cUTF_16_LE_BOM = "\xFF\xFETest";
    static std::string const cUTF_8_BOM     = "\xEF\xBB\xBFTest";
    static std::string const cUTF_32_BE_BOM = "\x00\x00\xFE\xFFTest";
    static std::string const cUTF_32_LE_BOM = "\xFF\xFE\x00\x00Test";
    static std::string const cUTF_7_BOM     = "\x2B\x2F\x76\x38\x2DTest";
```

but cUTF_32_BE_BOM and cUTF_32_LE_BOM result in an empty string in the first case and a string with length two in the second.

isn't a c++ string able to handle multiple '\0' chars in it while knowing its real size? I would expect a strlen to return 0 and 2 as length or an output stream only to consume until the first '\0'. But to be not initialized according to the written code is a bit strange in my perception.

Comment: It's not a bug.   The constructor of `std::string` (and the assignment operator, although you're not using those)  that accept a `const char *` use the contents up to the first nul character.   If you want a `std::string` that contains data past the end of a nul character (e.g. contains multiple C-strings) then it is possible by supplying the length as a second argument to the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will call the `std::string` constructor with a `const char*`: The length is already lost, and the equivalent of `strlen` (`std::char_traits<char>::length`) is called to get the size.

Normally, you would use `std::string_literals::operator""s` to not lose the `'\0'` characters, but that might not be feasible in the `::` scope. It would look like this:

```cpp
using namespace std::string_literals;
static std::string const cUTF_32_BE_BOM = "\x00\x00\xFE\xFFTest"s;
```

You can also call the constructor which takes a `const char*` and a length argument:

```cpp
static std::string const cUTF_32_BE_BOM("\x00\x00\xFE\xFFTest", 8);

// Or without hardcoding the size
static std::string const cUTF_32_BE_BOM("\x00\x00\xFE\xFFTest", sizeof("\x00\x00\xFE\xFFTest")-1);

// Or without copying the string
template<std::size_t N>
std::string make_string_from_literal(const char(&s)[N]) {
    return std::string(s, N-1);  // -1 for last '\0' character
}

static std::string const cUTF_32_BE_BOM = make_string_from_literal("\x00\x00\xFE\xFFTest");
```

Answer (score 1):

> isn't a c++ string able to handle multiple '\0' chars in it while knowing its real size?

Yes, but you haven't got a C++ string yet. The problem hits before you provide its initialiser.

> I would expect a strlen to return 0 and 2 as length or an output stream only to consume until the first '\0'.

Then you know that's because that's how C-strings work. Like the ones in your code. :)

> But to be not initialized according to the written code is a bit strange in my perception.

It is. ;)